# How to write a function in MySQL and check that it works

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a simple function in MySQL.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS BINOMIAL;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION BINOMIAL(g VARCHAR, s VARCHAR) RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
DECLARE x VARCHAR;
set x = CONCAT(g, s);
RETURN x;
END$$;
DELIMITER ;
SELECT BINOMIAL(Accessions.Genus, Accessions.Species) FROM Accessions;
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong and I can't find any good/understandable guides on function creation.

PhpMyAdmin throws this error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2".

From what I undersstand, the SELECT statement doesn't work because the function isn't being created.

Comment: There is no `LIMIT 0, 30` in the code you have shown.

Comment: PhpMyAdmin automatically adds a `LIMIT` clause to the end of your query so that it only shows the first 30 rows of results. Get rid of the `;` at the end so this can be added.

Comment: Try doing the function definition and the `SELECT` query as two separate operations in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Use the actual, real, MySQL command line client.

Comment: If I delete the ; at the end of the SELECT query I get "#1305 - FUNCTION paulh116_601.BINOMIAL does not exist ", so I must be doing something wrong with the function.